# QTableWidget edit only one column and leave the rest non-editable

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

In QT 4.7, I am trying to make one QTableWidgetItem in a QTableWidget Editable and the rest all columns should be read only for me. I am having problems here.

I have checked a number of samples through google and stackoverflow but failed to achieve this. Some of the options I tried are,

I create rows by calling insertRow(rownumber) for adding rows.

1. Trial 1: I do the following while inserting a row dynamically

   - Enable Edit triggers in the UI Dialog
   - Add columns using the following code for disabling edit

     `QTableWidgetItem qit("");
     qit.setflags(qit.flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable)
     qtable.setitem(row,column, &qit);`
   - And for others columns I don't set the flags

   This above approach did not work. I am able edit all columns (even the one I negated the editable option)
2. Trial 2:
   Do all the above with just `qtable.setEditTriggers(Qt::NoEditTriggers)` and then set the columns editable wherever required.

   But this option renders all columns non-editable.

But I don't see anyone complaining like this in any forums. So I must be making some stupid mistake.

Have someone come across such an issue, if yes please help by answering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Working example of [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html)**

First item in added row is editable, second one is not editable.

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Prepare layout
    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow;
    QTableWidget *tablewidget = new QTableWidget;
    window->setCentralWidget(tablewidget);

    // Add data
    tablewidget->insertRow(0);
    tablewidget->insertColumn(0);
    tablewidget->insertColumn(1);

    QTableWidgetItem *item;
    item = new QTableWidgetItem("editable");
    tablewidget->setItem(0,0,item);

    item = new QTableWidgetItem("non editable");
    item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable); // non editable
    tablewidget->setItem(0,1,item);

    window->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```